# How to dance around a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, gridworld

I'm trying to check whether or not a move is legal in the game Othello, using eclipse and gridworld. The first thing I do to the location is check if it is valid, but in order to check the validity location, it needs to not be null. The problem is, one of the requirements of it being a legal move is that it is null/empty/unoccupied. How do I avoid this? I have pointed out where the error is supposedly at. (Sorry if this confused anyone.)

```
public boolean isLegal(Location loc1)
{
    boolean isLegal = false;
    String currentColor = currentPlayer.getColor();
    int row = loc1.getRow();
    int col = loc1.getCol();
    if(board.isValid(loc1))
    {
        if(board.get(loc1) == null)
        {
            for(Location tempLoc : board.getValidAdjacentLocations(loc1))
            {
                **if(!board.get(tempLoc).equals(currentColor))**
                {
                    if((row != tempLoc.getRow()) && (col == tempLoc.getCol()))
                    {
                        //count up column
                        if(tempLoc.getRow() < row)
                        {
                            for(int i = row; i > 1;)
                            {
                                Location tempLoc2 = new Location(i-2, col);
                                if(!board.get(tempLoc2).equals(currentColor))
                                {
                                    i--;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    i=-1;
                                    isLegal = true;
                                }   
                            }
                        }
                        //count down column
                        else
                        {
                            for(int i = row; i < 6;)
                            {
                                Location tempLoc2 = new Location(i+2, col);
                                if(!board.get(tempLoc2).equals(currentColor))
                                {
                                    i++;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    i=9;
                                    isLegal = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if(col != tempLoc.getCol() && row == tempLoc.getRow())
                    {
                        //count right row
                        if(col > tempLoc.getCol())
                        {
                            for(int i = col; i > 1;)
                            {
                                Location tempLoc2 = new Location(row, i-2);
                                if(!board.get(tempLoc2).equals(currentColor))
                                {
                                    i--;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    i=-1;
                                    isLegal = true;
                                }   
                            }
                        }
                        //count left row
                        else
                        {
                            for(int i = col; i < 6;)
                            {
                                Location tempLoc2 = new Location(row, i+2);
                                if(!board.get(tempLoc2).equals(currentColor))
                                {
                                    i++;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    i=9;
                                    isLegal = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {   //count up/right diag
                        if(row-1 == tempLoc.getRow() && col+1 == tempLoc.getCol())
                        {
                            int j = col;
                            for(int i = row; i > 1;)
                            {
                                Location tempLoc2 = new Location(i-1, j+1);
                                if(!board.get(tempLoc2).equals(currentColor))
                                {
                                    i--;
                                    j++;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    i=-1;
                                    isLegal = true;
                                }   
                            }
                        }
                        //count down/left diag
                        else if(row+1 == tempLoc.getRow() && col-1 == tempLoc.getCol())
                        {
                            int i = row;
                            for(int j = col; j > 1;)
                            {
                                Location tempLoc2 = new Location(i+1, j-1);
                                if(!board.get(tempLoc2).equals(currentColor))
                                {
                                    i++;
                                    j--;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    i=9;
                                    isLegal = true;
                                }   
                            }
                        }
                        //count up/left diag
                        else if(row-1 == tempLoc.getRow() && col-1 == tempLoc.getCol())
                        {
                            int j = col;
                            for(int i = row; i > 1;)
                            {
                                Location tempLoc2 = new Location(i-1, j-1);
                                if(!board.get(tempLoc2).equals(currentColor))
                                {
                                    i--;
                                    j--;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    i=-1;
                                    isLegal = true;
                                }   
                            }
                        }
                        //count down/right diag
                        else
                        {
                            int j = col;
                            for(int i = row; i > 6;)
                            {
                                Location tempLoc2 = new Location(i+1, j+1);
                                if(!board.get(tempLoc2).equals(currentColor))
                                {
                                    i++;
                                    j++;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    i=-1;
                                    isLegal = true;
                                }   
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return isLegal;
}
```

Comment: You can test whether a reference is null with `if (ref == null)`...

Comment: I have done that. The problem is I need to work with this null location, but I can't if it's null. That's my problem. I'm trying to figure out alternate code that will accomplish the same thing yet not have a NullPointerException.

Comment: Once you have established that the reference is null, then don't attempt to call any member methods through it.

Comment: I have to be able to check if the locations in the row/column/diagonal fit all the requirements to make the move legal. The simplest way to do this is to use the `getValidAdjacentLocations()` method, but in order to do so, the location can't be null. But it needs to be null in order to be a legal move.

Comment: Then you have engineered yourself into a paradox, and need to reconsider your design...

Answer (score 3):

**One solution is to change your design so that no location is ever `null`.**

You seem to have equated `null` with "unoccupied" or "empty". Instead create all positions first (there aren't many of them on an Othello board) and initialize them all with `boolean occupied = false` or an equivalent member variable. Then you'd have:

```
if ( !board.get(loc1).isOccupied() ) { /*stuff*/ }
```

instead of a null check.

This is better object oriented design because an empty location is still a location, and should be manipulable.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to take a break for now, but I am very excited to try this!

Comment: I'd even go a bit further. I'd leave a set of Locations in the Board class but I'd also create a Coordinates class. Then a Location would have Coordinates and you could use board.get(coordinates) which would return a Location which would have the method paislee mentioned isOccupied() (and possibly others). Passing to a method a Location to get a Location seems weird to me. Also I'd refactor this code if I were you.

Comment: That seems like a good idea. I'll be sure to try that too. Thank you for the insight!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `null` as a part of your logic.
`null` it's not a state, it is a **symbol that there is no state**.
You should leave `null` out of your logic, then if some reference is `null`, you know that for sure something really nasty happen, not related to your model. Inside `Location` you can create for example a method `isEmpty()` or similar, so you can easily avoid comparing to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `enum` with the values `BLACK`, `WHITE` and `VACANT`, instead of a `String`, to store what colour token is at each location.  Return the same `enum` from `getColor()` in the `Player` class.